# One Page fadeIn & fadeOut Transition Logic

Tags: jquery, arrays, logic

I am making a one-page website for a client. There are 3 different menu groups, but in this example i simplified it to one menu and less content.

I have this navigation:

```
    <nav>
        <ul id="main" class="toggle">
            <li><a id="design" href="#">DESIGN</a></li>
            <li><a id="contactus" href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
            <li><a id="aboutus" href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li><a id="news" href="#">NEWS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

And Divs like that below:

```
<div class="designcontent">
Design Content Here
</div>
<div class="aboutuscontent">
About us Content Here      
</div>
```

So if i were to click on DESIGN it would show designcontent, and then if i were to click ABOUT US it would show aboutuscontent and so on.

I am asking for a short-hand code of

```
        $("#design").click(function(){
        $('.homecontent').fadeOut(500);
        $('.designcontent').delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
        return false;
        });

        $("#home").click(function(){
        $('.designcontent').fadeOut(500);
        $('.homecontent').delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
        return false;
        });
```

Because it gets more and more complicated if there are many pages, and if my client wants to add a new page.

I have this jQuery code below to get id's and use them in Array and hide the contents on load:

```
$('#main li a').each(function(){
  liIds.push('.'+ $(this).attr('id')+'content');
  $(''+liIds).hide();   
})
```

What i am missing is, clicking on menu links and showing the correct content each time a menu is clicked.

I hope my question is clear enough, if not i can provide visual examples on jsFiddle.

Thanks for taking time to read my question

My problem is solved using:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    var cls = $(this).attr('id')
     $('.' + cls + 'content').addClass('onpage');
    $('.onpage').fadeOut(500);
    $('.' + cls + 'content').delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
    return false;
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use similar name for `id` of the anchor and it's target element's `class`:

html:

```
<li><a id="design" href="#">DESIGN</a></li> 

<div class="design content">
   Design Content Here
</div>
```

js:

```
$("ul li a").click(function(){
    var cls = $(this).attr('id')
    $(".content").fadeOut(500);
    $('.' + cls).delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
    return false;
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QuKhN/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works but the problem is, i have many other divs like in header, in footer. 
Perhaps adding classes like "active" to content divs and switching them each time could help, if i used $(".active").fadeOut(500); ?
Just a thought.

Comment: @Tumay yes, that was an example, you can instead of div select content tags by a class name, try the updated answer.

Comment: thanks @undefined

Using a seperate class solved my problem for now :) Just another thing left, but that is not related with the question i asked here. If i can't solve it, i might bug again :)