# Click & Show only if there is an existing div class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

My old question: [One Page fadeIn & fadeOut Transition Logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373619/one-page-fadein-fadeout-transition-logic)

The code works pretty good, but i have an issue. In my navigation system there are menu's with submenus, aka drop-down menus. So if a menu link is clicked with no content, but sub-menus, the content page is loaded blank, until i click something that actually has a content class.

Here is a simple jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/QuKhN/1/

I want it to load content, only if there is content corresponding to the menu link id. So if "Contact Us" is clicked in this example, i don't want it to try to load an un-existing div called "contactus content".

Is this possible?
I have tried few things with hasClass() function, but i failed to succeed.

Thanks for taking time to read and understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
$("ul li a ").click(function() {
    var cls = $(this).attr('id')
    if ($('div.content.' + cls).length > 0) {  
        $(".content").fadeOut(500);
        $('.' + cls).delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
    }
    return false;
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QuKhN/4/)

Comment: Thank you, this worked the best :) Just like i wanted it to be.

Answer (score 1):

You could select the element that you are about to display and use the length property to make sure that there is such an element. Length will be greater than zero.

Something like this:

```
$("ul li a ").click(function(){
    var cls = $(this).attr('id');
    // Fade out the previous content no matter what
    $(".content").fadeOut(500);
    // Check if there is content to display using length
    if ($('.' + cls).length > 0) {
       // Will only display content if it exist
       $('.' + cls).delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
    }
    return false;
})​;​
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/QuKhN/2/

**Note:**

This rely on that you don't use those classes on some other elements, but so does the rest of your script, so I guess that would be fine in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, really appreciate it. I don't know why, but it didn't work on my website, though it works with the structure given above in my question. Must be my bad, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Try `hasClass`:

```
$("ul li a ").click(function(){
    var cls = $(this).attr('id')
    $(".content").fadeOut(500);
    if($("div").hasClass(cls)){
       $('.' + cls).delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
    }
    return false;
})​
```

Comment: Thanks, sounds good but i couldn't get it to work "perfectly" appreciate your effort!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("ul li a").filter(function(){
    return $('.'+this.id).length>0;
}).click(function(){
    var cls = $(this).attr('id')

    $(".content").fadeOut(500);
    $('.' + cls).delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
    return false;
})​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UYSqm/)

Comment: Sorry i couldn't try your solution, i was trying other ones and just seen yours, but thank you very much!

Comment: @Tumay There is a demo, you could see.